# What causes sympy subs to sometimes not work?

Tags: sympy

I'm evaluating multiple expression and the result looks like this. Single variable replacement works, not sure if there is maybe an issue with some cases.

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example. It should show how `a_star` is created. Also, as you probably know, code as image usually isn't well-received on SO.  Apart from that, you could try putting your dictionary variable between quotes `d = dict('p0'=0.1, ...)`.

Comment: So the trick is that you *absolutely can not ever* use dict(...) with sympy args like this becuase of the way both sympy and python work. It is obvious once you think about it (the keys are strings in the above example when we need them to be sympy objects).

It is easy to fall into this trap and it fails without error.

Comment: Well, this depends on how you created the expressions. You can easily use a dict like this if you created `a_star` from the **same** sympy variables. But it seems it was created from strings.  As the question doesn't show how the expression was created, it's hard to tell.